# Classical Rabbinic Literature in English or French

Tags: product-recommendation

Do you know if these books exist in English or French?

- Sifre
- Sifra
- Tosefta
- Beraytot deRebbi Hoshayah and Bar Kappara
- Barayta deRebbi Yishmoel
- Mekhilta
- Mekhilta deRebbi Akiva (aka "Mekhilta deRebbi Shimon bar Yohaï")

  Midrashim of Tannaim :
- Seder Olam Rabbah
- Otyot DeRabbi Akiva
- Barayta deMelekhet haMishkan.

Comment: wow qui est une longue liste

Answer (score 3):

Sifre in English, Yale University Press, translated by Reuven Hammer.

[Sefer Ha-Qabbalah](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0827609167) by Avraham Ibn Daud, The Littman Library of Jewish Civilization, translated by Gerson D. Cohen

[Mekilta de-Rabbi Ishmael](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0827606788), The JPS Library of Jewish Classics, translation by Jacob Z. Lauterbach

[Tosefta](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1619702622), Hendrickson Publishers, translation by Jacob Neusner

[Mekhilta deRebbi Shimon bar Yohaï](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0827607997), The Jewish Publication Society, translation by W. David Nelson

[Seder Olam Rabbah](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0765760215), Jason Aronson, Inc. Publishers, edited by Heinrich W. Guggenheimer

Although this is not exactly the Brayta of 32 Rules, Rabbi Adin Even Yisroel Steinsaltz's [English Reference Guide to the Talmud](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592643124), Random House, has a section called "The Principles of Talmudic Hermeneutics" which covers that material in detail.

I recall there was an English translation of "The Letters of Rabbi Akiva" in the late 1960's or early 1970's. It might be found on EBay or a used bookstore.

Comment: Thanks! Why did you mention the sefer ha-kabala?

Comment: @far22, the Seder Olam Rabbah is essentially a history. It seemed like this might be a substitute for the subject.